# ASP/C# SharePoint web part... OnMouseOver not responding

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sharepoint

Here are the salient lines in VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="StudentHeader.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl" %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd" runat="server" OnMouseOver="LightUpDD" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="400px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="<Select Student>" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Note OnMouseOver="LightUpDD" and ID="dd".

I have a LightUpDD function in VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs:

```
    protected void LightUpDD(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dd.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Debugging gives me a run-time error as soon as I float my mouse over the DropDownList control:

**Unhandled exception at line 575, column 302 in http://spdevelopment:8282/studentheader/SitePages/Home.aspx
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'LightUpDD' is undefined.**

This is strictly a cosmetic idea, so it's not crucial, but I'm curious as to why I get the error for a function that clearly (at least to me) exists and compiles.

Thanks for any help!

Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this is a wrong method of getting an HTML element to "light up" as you put it. There is no need to go to the server and back (postback / roundtrip) to do this. You can accomplish this easily on client side without having to wait.
Use jQuery or javascript to enable or disable an element.
You need to remember that server side controls have auto-generated client ID.
So, when you point to an element you need to use the following approach:
Example:

```
    jQuery Example:      var elem = $('#<%=dd.ClientID%>');
    JavaScript Example:  var elem = document.getElementById("<%=dd.ClientID%>");
```

You can then manipulate this element as you see fit.
Example (credits for this example to @[Claudio Redi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245860/claudio-redi)):

```
    $('#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>').click(function(){
      if ($('#<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').prop('disabled') != true)
        $('#<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
          else
        $('#<%= DropDownList2.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', false);
      })
```

Good luck friend!
PS.
For future reference, you should avoid tagging your question with SharePoint unless it is related to SharePoint features. This is "pure" ASP / JS type of stuff. If you tag it properly, you'll get a much better chance in replies.